# Swt + Jface application

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I want to use some libraries from eclipse to create standalone application. 
JFace provides for instance `SourceViewer`, which is great if you need to show some code in your app (that is what i need). `SourceViewer` looks like that eclipse editor area and you can configure it as you want. It is really great.

The `SourceViewer` is configured via

```
public void configure(SourceViewerConfiguration configuration)
```

There is `JavaSourceViewerConfiguration`, which is subclass of `SourceViewerConfiguration` and it should be good if you want show Java code.

This is `JavaSourceViewerConfiguration` constructor.

```
public JavaSourceViewerConfiguration(IColorManager colorManager, IPreferenceStore preferenceStore, ITextEditor editor, String partitioning)
```

The last two parameters could be null, so the **QUESTION is how to obtain properly configured IColorManager and IPreferenceStore instances?**

**What i currently have:**

```
SourceViewer sv = new SourceViewer(sf, new CompositeRuler(), SWT.NONE);
LineNumberRulerColumn lnRuler = new LineNumberRulerColumn();
sv.addVerticalRulerColumn(lnRuler);

PreferenceStore pf = new PreferenceStore();
IColorManager cm = (new JavaTextTools(pf)).getColorManager();
sv.configure(new JavaSourceViewerConfiguration(cm, pf, null, null));
```

**But in this code i always got**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.JavaSourceViewerConfiguration.getConfiguredTextHoverStateMasks(JavaSourceViewerConfiguration.java:639)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewer.configure(SourceViewer.java:507)
    at swtPokus.Main.main(Main.java:37)
```

I think it is because that `PreferenceStore pf` should be somehow configured so it contains keys and values which are used by the SourceViewer.
**Question2 is where to get those value for PreferenceStore?**

Comment: Since `JavaSourceViewerConfiguration` is part of the Eclipse JDT plugins it very probably will only work in an Eclipse plugin.

Comment: @greg-449: i think it is just about how to fill the PreferenceStore.

Comment: The NPE at line 639 is due to a reference to `JavaPlugin.getDefault()` which has not been initialized. JavaSourceViewerConfiguration has a very large number of dependencies on other Eclipse plugins and must be run in an Eclipse plugin.

Comment: @Krab have you considered making it an Eclipse RCP application, with very few dependencies on `org.eclipse` bundles?

Comment: @VladIlie: didn't know about RCP, thanks!

Comment: @greg-449: yes you are right, it will be propably very hard to use it other than inside a plugin